# Why I can't retrieve array values?

Tags: java, arrays, string, null

I want to print the stored array values.But When I do so it prints only null values. Whats wrong with my code. When I check the array length(). It prints the length. But when I try to retrieve the values it gives only null values.

```
 public class StoreVal
{
static String[] values1=new String[100];
    static String[] kmvalues1=new String[200];

public static void setvalues()
{
    try
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        BufferedReader b1=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d://values//kmeans0.txt"));
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        BufferedReader b2=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d://values//kmeans1.txt"));
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        BufferedReader b3=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d://values//kmeans2.txt"));
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        BufferedReader b4=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d://values//kmeans3.txt"));



        String km1 = null;
        String km2 = null;
        String km3 = null;
        String km4 = null;





        while((km1=b1.readLine())!=null)
        {

            int i=0;
            values1[i]=km1;
            System.out.println(values1[i]);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    values();
}



public static void values()
{


    for(int x=0;x<values1.length;x++)
    {
        System.out.println(values1[x]);  // this line prints only null
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{

    setvalues();

}


}
```

Comment: I think variable "i" is always set to zero. You probably need to set it outside the read loop and increment it at the end of each read

Answer (score 0):

```
 while((km1=b1.readLine())!=null)
    {

        int i=0;
        values1[i]=km1;
        System.out.println(values1[i]);
    }
```

Makes me feel that you are inserting the value only for `values1[0]` !

You need to set `int i=0` above the while loop and increment it  `i++;` inside the loop.

```
int i=0;     
while((km1=b1.readLine())!=null)
{
     values1[i]=km1;
     System.out.println(values1[i]);
     i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment the counter variable `i` in your loop:

```
int i = 0;
while((km1 = b1.readLine()) != null) {
    values1[i] = km1;
    System.out.println(values1[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting the value for the first element of your array.

```
    while((km1=b1.readLine())!=null)
    {

        int i=0;
        values1[i]=km1;
        System.out.println(values1[i]);
    }
```

You need this:

```
int i = 0;
while((km1=b1.readLine())!=null)
    {

        values1[i]=km1;
        System.out.println(values1[i++]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you don't increment the **i** variable (another problem is that **i** variable is initialized inside the loop).

In place of the while loop try this:

```
for(int i=0; i< values1.length;i++)
    {
        if((km1=b1.readLine())==null)break;
         values1[i]=km1;
         System.out.println(values1[i]);
}
```

NOTE: In this way you never exceed the values1 length.

Comment: produc
built
access
expect
null

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as has been said, you've simply forgotten to increment the value of `i` in each iteration of the `while` loop, so the arrays values remian null - nothing is assigned to them.